# A custom widget created with PyQt doesn't load on boot but loads when program is started from command line

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, pyqt

I've created a GUI using PyQt. I'm using a custom widget: a modified version of the code from here: https://github.com/juancarlospaco/qslider/blob/master/qslider/qslider.py

My program is set to run when booted, and works perfectly. However, these QSwitches from the above qslider.py do NOT load on boot (They don't show up on the screen at all, it is just blank where they're supposed to be)

When I exit the program loaded from boot and run the same program by executing it from the  command line, the QSwitches from qslider.py  work correctly (they show up on the screen where they're supposed to be).

What could be causing this error.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake. I didn't add the file paths for the images I was using for the custom widget so on boot, it wasn't able to locate them!